# A simple concept question regarding Bootstrapping

Tags: regression, prediction, bootstrap, computational-statistics, k-nearest-neighbour

I am having a difficulty understanding whether I can use the bootstrapping method for prediction.

First off, my data is as follows.
[image]

where personal Income is the dependent variable (y), and GPA, Age, etc., are independent variables (x). I have about 9 different independent variables that are not shown here.

What I'm trying to do here is to predict a person's income when all the independent variables are plugged in.
I used both linear regression and KNN, but the results were dissatisfying.
Primary reason for the bad outcome, I believe, is the number of sample which is about 50.

So I was wondering if the results could be more accurate if I use the bootstrapping method to get a larger sample size, and use that data set to predict the Y value.

I do not know if this would get me a better result, or is totally meaningless.
(Since bootstrapping needs to have sample that resembles the population).

Comment: Are you talking about bootstrap sampling or bootstrap aggregation?

Comment: Your terminology for 'dependent variables' and 'independent variables' appears to be incorrect, so it was edited. Please check to see that it captures your meaning (the edit seems right to me) and to improve your understanding.

Comment: you are correct. Thx for the edit

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid using the bootstrap to improve predictions like this is, as you suggest, meaningless. The bootstrap is mainly a method for assesssing the bias and variability of estimators. It is certainly not a method for creating something out of nothing: it can't show you anything that isn't already present in the data. For a bootstrap estimate to make sense, the bootstrap pseudosamples must be drawn to be the same size as the original sample.

You are right to suspect the small sample as a reason your predictions are bad; it is quite risky to fit 9 predictors with only 50 observations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. So I guess the only way to fix the inaccuray is through getting more sample.. :)